# Run message box when cell value time is exceed system time

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file.

I wish to write a Excel vba to compare the system time and the cell value time.

If system time is exceed the cell value time, it will show a pop out message to inform user that, the time is exceed.

My file will look like this:

[image]

I have been research a while but seem like only vba code will able to complete this requirement.

Comment: You didn't mention the event on which the validation will occur. Do you wants to do this on a click of a button?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TimeCheck()

Dim ValueTime As Date
Dim SysTime As Date

SysTime = Now()

Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
'Column 14 stands for N, change as required


For I = 6 To Finalrow
'6 stands for first row filled with value, change as required
    ValueTime = Cells(I, 14).Value
    If TimeValue(ValueTime) < TimeValue(SysTime) Then
        Cells(I, 14).Offset(, 1).Value = "Time is exceeeded" '1 is offsetting to column O. Use 2 for column P, 3 for Q and so on, as you prefer.
            MsgBox ("Time is exceeeded for user entry in N" & I)
            'To store the time error in adjacent O column cells, and to popup for each error
        'Remove either as required - esp MsgBox, it is very annoying - put only because you asked in original question
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kimberly, have you checked if the input (N column) is time? Any other type of value fed in them can show this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only advise the guest that the time input does not exceed the current, you don't need a vba (intersect will be one way) you can use the validate date [image]

and you can customize the input msg and also the error msg if the value isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
Sub TimeNow()
    Dim cValue As Date '// Cell Value
    Dim sTime As Date '// System

    cValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    sTime = TimeValue(Now)

    If sTime > cValue Then
        MsgBox "TiMe iS Up. STOP " & TimeValue(Now)
    Else: Exit Sub
        'or do something
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Hi, can I know B2 will be the time value that is being auto generated in column N?

Comment: Yes, B2 is just an example I used when i was testing the code

Comment: is that possible that I change it to cValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N:N").Value
as I wish it to check the last value on column N?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function TimeValue, which returns the value of time as a number between 0 and 1. Posting a simple code to check on cell N6 alone.

/// You may, of course, use loops to check for a range of cells, or use the excel events, or keyboard shortcuts to run the macro.///

```
Sub TimeCheck()

Dim ValueTime As Date
Dim SysTime As Date

ValueTime = Range("N6").Value
SysTime = Now()

If TimeValue(ValueTime) < TimeValue(SysTime) Then
    MsgBox ("Time is exceeeded")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, how if the data is being filled after N6? I mean I wish to let it keep checking the last row time value in column N...will it possible?

Comment: Hi, it's possible. See my second answer. It will check uptil last filled row.